# What is the purpose of these removable "collars" on ceramic light fixtures

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, junction-box

This fixture happens to be plastic, but all my ceiling juntion box mounted 600w rated light fixtures have a removable collar. I don't see the point in this extra part. Is there some sort of shade I can install? I assume if you had a heavy bulb that you'd just use an E39 size socket instead of the E26 socket.

[image: Removed collar]

Comment: I'm used to seeing those when there is a shade or something to attach, but I also wonder what role it would have in insulating the plastic base and wiring it covers from heat generated by an incandescent bulb.

Comment: It holds the socket into the fixture on the original porcelain fixtures, and as mentioned it can be used to attach a shade or reflector.

Comment: Did you mean 600W or 60W ?

Comment: 600 watts. The ceramic ones are rated for 600 watts

Comment: What is the application of this bulb? Googling 600W turned up lights for plant growing?

Comment: @DaveInCaz I've never seen a 600W bulb personally, I have no idea what they were used for before marajunia hydroponics. I think Ceramic fixtures were just always rated for 600W. [This bulb](https://www.amazon.com/Meridian-Equivalent-Daylight-Non-Dimmable-Replacement/dp/B01FGCF7S6/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1469450721&sr=8-6&keywords=300w+led+bulb) is designed to replace a 300W bulb, but only draws 33W. I use it in my garage Despite the fact that I could plug it into a desk lamp rated for 40W, the ceramic E26-E39 adapter it came with said it was rated for 600 watts.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the metal screw socket would be touchable without the plastic ring in place. When the bulb is lit, I believe that would be hot (energized).

Since they may use the same base for different size screw fittings, the ring is possibly designed to protect from shock hazard but being a separate component allows the base to accommodate various sized sockets.

The specific scenario I can think of when this would be important is when screwing in a new bulb to replace a dead one. The circuit could unknowingly be on (since the bulb is dead), and you could get a shock when the bulb made the circuit.

Comment: Wired correctly the shell would never be hot, only the small tab in the middle. It is also not desigend for different sized sockets. An edison socket is an edison socket (in North America at least).

Comment: The socket would be electrified when A) the circuit is switched on and B) a functional bulb is screwed in. If it were not, there would be no way to complete the circuit from the tab in the middle. Granted the tab is wired to the switched live wire (in 120V single phase) but you could still get a shock from the neutral when the lamp is on.  If it were in a 240V single-phase or perhaps 3-phase then it would be the same situation but of course there is no neutral.

Comment: Also, there are several common sizes of ES sockets in the USA, not only one. The OP even mentioned a few types. I've seen larger variants for like a large sodium-style bulb (not sure of the exact type / terminology) and obviously there are the smaller ones for say candelabra type bulbs. These are all Edison sockets; seems plausible to me a base such as in the question could accommodate any of those variations.

Comment: No, if wired correctly the shell would NOT be "electrified". That is the whole point. And in a residential setting there is no 240V lighting, so again, the shell would not be live.

Comment: And sorry, I should have said medium base socket, not Edison socket. This is a typical keyless fixture. They come in medium base. Not mogul, not intermediate, not candelabra.

Comment: I just tried it with a voltmeter. Got 110V from metal threaded socket to ground when lamp was lit.  Also the OP didn't say residential, in fact he mentioned a 600W bulb (!) which doesn't sound residential to me, though I guess it is possible.

Comment: If you got 120V to the shell it is wired wrong. ......... And he mentioned 600W rated fixture. Keyless fixtures are rated for 600W for some reason. ...... Also, this is the "Home Improvement" part of the site. I (rightfully) assume discussions are regarding **home** improvement.